# ADPrep error trying to upgrade Windows 2012 server to DC in 2008 domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

Trying to promote a Windows 2012 server to DC in a 2008 domain and after passing all prerequisites and beginning the process, I get an error stating:

> adprep was unable to bind to any domain controller

Here is the output from the debug log:

> [2013/11/19:01:07:51.518] Adprep created the log file
>   'C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20131119010751\ADPrep.log'
>   [2013/11/19:01:07:51.518] Adprep successfully initialized global
>   variables.
>
> [Status/Consequence]
>
> Adprep is continuing. [2013/11/19:01:07:51.542] Adprep was about to
>   call the following LDAP API. ldap_search_s(). The base entry to start
>   the search is CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com.
>   [2013/11/19:01:07:51.543] LDAP API ldap_search_s() finished, return
>   code is 0x0  [2013/11/19:01:07:51.543] Adprep was about to call the
>   following LDAP API. ldap_search_s(). The base entry to start the
>   search is
>   CN=ZION,CN=Servers,CN=domain,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com. [2013/11/19:01:07:51.544] LDAP API ldap_search_s() finished, return
>   code is 0x0  [2013/11/19:01:07:51.544] Adprep was about to call the
>   following LDAP API. ldap_search_s(). The base entry to start the
>   search is CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com.
>   [2013/11/19:01:07:51.545] LDAP API ldap_search_s() finished, return
>   code is 0x0  [2013/11/19:01:08:10.901] Adprep was unable to bind to
>   any Domain Controller (DC) over Remote Procedure Call (RPC) in the
>   Active Directory Domain domain.com. [2013/11/19:01:08:10.901] Adprep
>   encountered a Win32 error.
>
> Error code: 0x6be Error message: The remote procedure call failed.
>
> DSID Info: DSID: 0x18111880 winerror = 0x6be NT BUILD: 9600 NT BUILD:
>   16384
>
> [2013/11/19:01:08:10.901] Adprep could not discover the Schema FSMO.
>   The Schema FSMO must be discoverable for this operation to proceed.
>
> [Status/Consequence]
>
> The Active Directory Domain Services schema is not upgraded.
>
> [User Action]
>
> Check the log file ADPrep.log in the
>   C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20131119010751 directory for possible
>   cause of failure. [2013/11/19:01:08:10.901] Adprep encountered a Win32
>   error.
>
> Error code: 0x6be Error message: The remote procedure call failed.
>
> DSID Info: DSID: 0x18111880 winerror = 0x6be NT BUILD: 9600 NT BUILD:
>   16384
>
> [2013/11/19:01:08:10.901] Adprep was unable to check the specified
>   user's group membership.
>
> [Status/Consequence]
>
> Adprep has stopped without making changes.
>
> [User Action]
>
> Verify the specified user is a member of Enterprise Admins group and
>   Schema Admins group if /forestprep is specified, or is a member of
>   Domain Admins group if /domainprep is specified, or is a member of
>   Enterprise Admins group if /rodcprep is specified .
>   [2013/11/19:01:08:10.901] Adprep encountered a Win32 error.
>
> Error code: 0x6be Error message: The remote procedure call failed.
>
> DSID Info: DSID: 0x18111880 winerror = 0x6be NT BUILD: 9600 NT BUILD:
>   16384

Any ideas where to look? I have verified connectivity to the DC and this server has no issues accessing network resources.

Comment: Is the user under which you're running the prep a member of the Enterprise Admins group, the Domain Admins group and the Schema Admins group?

Comment: I'm running it using the default Administrator user, which is a member of all three groups you listed